# Why slick slider is not adaptive?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why when I reduce screen size my slick slider is not adaptive?

settings of slick:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.head-slider__slider').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 1000,
  });
});
```

code structure of slider:

```css
.head-slider {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 min-height: 900px;
 background: url(../img/sliders/slide_img.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: fixed;
 .head-slider__slider {
  width: 100%;
  .slider__slide {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: space-around;
   min-height: 500px;
   .slide__slide-header {
    h2 {
     font-size: 7rem;
     font-family: @FfontRaleway;
     font-weight: @WfontSemiBold;
     color: @whiteColor;
    }
   }
   .slide__slide-description {
    font-size: 5rem;
    font-family: @FfontRaleway;
    font-weight: @WfontLight;
    color: @whiteColor;
   }
   .slide__slide-buttons {
    a {
     .lightButtons(@whiteColor);
     margin-right: 1%;
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

```html
 <section class="head-slider">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="head-slider__slider">
    <div class="slider__slide">
     <div class="slide__slide-header">
      <h2>Expire</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="slide__slide-description">
      <p>Professionaly designed, carefully made for your enjoyement</p>
     </div>
     <div class="slide__slide-buttons">
      <a href="#">Explore</a>
      <a href="#">Learn more</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!--slide-end-->
    <div class="slider__slide">
     <div class="slide__slide-header">
      <h2>Expire</h2>
      <object data="" type=""></object>
     </div>
     <div class="slide__slide-description">
      <p>Professionaly designed, carefully made for your enjoyement</p>
     </div>
     <div class="slide__slide-buttons">
      <a href="#">Explore</a>
      <a href="#">Learn more</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!--slide-end-->
    <div class="slider__slide">
     <div class="slide__slide-header">
      <h2>Expire</h2>
      <object data="" type=""></object>
     </div>
     <div class="slide__slide-description">
      <p>Professionaly designed, carefully made for your enjoyement</p>
     </div>
     <div class="slide__slide-buttons">
      <a href="#">Explore</a>
      <a href="#">Learn more</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!--slide-end-->
    <div class="slider__slide">
     <div class="slide__slide-header">
      <h2>Expire</h2>
      <object data="" type=""></object>
     </div>
     <div class="slide__slide-description">
      <p>Professionaly designed, carefully made for your enjoyement</p>
     </div>
     <div class="slide__slide-buttons">
      <a href="#">Explore</a>
      <a href="#">Learn more</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!--slide-end-->  
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
```

I tryed delete `display: flex` for `.head-slider__slider` and adaptive begins work, but the slider has moved upwards, but it needs to be centered.

Example: http://uzinouzi.github.io/testtemplate

P.S. Sorry for my English, I am from Belarussia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your **container** css class has **max-width:1170px**, which doesnt decresae on small screens.
The **head-slider__slider** class has **width:100%**, which leads to slick slider taking 1170px width.

add this media query to ur css file

```
@media(max-width:1170px){
 .container{
   width:100%
  }
}
```